# NOT IN WHERE Clause Error

Tags: mysql, sql, printf, notin

I want to fetch a list of **items** from my database that are not currently within my **item** array.

I have researched that '**NOT IN**' is the perfect solution to do multiple != '**NOT EQUAL TO**' in large quantities.

But my code to generate the list:

```
    echo $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE profile_id='%s' AND id NOT IN (%s)", $table_array[$item], $profile_id, implode(',', $shop_window_items));
```

Causes this error:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE profile_id='945b4dbf5bf8ee1ac08a73e9e25a939772c9c9b8' AND id NOT IN (4d96b83d18a8c2db79089ac002e346fd9dea5c43,3803bb535015174e9675090fbb680a5f286ba6bf,58f07f83a8ea10ec4db9c8b7c7f39f0a6c3a2079,57c2db2ce32925bcb49b83e22513ca74cc9bcadc)Unknown column '4d96b83d18a8c2db79089ac002e346fd9dea5c43' in 'where clause
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, for very large quantities, not in is far from perfect.  Quite simply it's slow.  Better options are not exists and, depending on the db type, minus/except.

Comment: by large quantities I meant, upto 8 values, so in terms of efficieny as of this function, its very practical for my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need single quotes around strings, otherwise they are assumed to be system names.

```
...NOT IN ('%s')", $table_array[$item], $profile_id, implode("','", ...
           ^  ^                                               ^ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need quotes around the values inside the `IN`

```
echo $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE profile_id='%s' AND id NOT IN (%s)", $table_array[$item], $profile_id, "'" . implode("','", $shop_window_items) . "'");
```

Comment: Also need quotes around `%s`

Comment: I put them on either side of the implode? Probably not as pretty as Aarolama's solution.

Comment: That will only put single quotes *between* the strings, not at the beginning and end; thus the need for single quotes around `%s`

Comment: I have the quotes on the outside of the implode. `"'" . implode("','", array('test','test','test')) . "'"` will end up like `'test','test','test'`.

Comment: I must have overlooked them. My apologies.